# Query SyntaxError

Tags: sql, case

I'm fairly new to SQL. I simply want to generate a table and fill in some value under certain condition. Do you see any Syntax Error in this query? Very certain that the error is within the case statement because without the case statement, the table gets generated just fine.

```
q = "select tbuc.csId, tbui.role_type, 
(case when tbui.role_type = "ROLE_USER" then 1 else 0 end) as
assignment_submitted FROM tb_user_click tbuc, tb_user_info tbui WHERE 
tbui.user_id = tbuc.uId and tbuc.csId = tbui.class_section_id;"
```

Also tried using IIF, the error message is as followed:

```
File "1.py", line 118
q = "select tbuc.csId, tbui.role_type,IIF(role_type = "ROLE_USER", 1, 0) 
as assignment_submitted FROM tb_user_click tbuc, tb_user_info tbui 
WHERE tbui.user_id = tbuc.uId and tbuc.csId = tbui.class_section_id;"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The syntax highlighting should give this one away.

Comment: Probably the unescaped double-quotes around `ROLE_USER`

Comment: 1:st query is valid ANSI SQL syntax. UID is a product specific resever word. Double quote "uId" to be safe. 2:nd query contains product specific IIF function.

Comment: But the problem is the double quotes around ROLE_USED. Double quotes are for object names (e.g. columns). String literals have single quotes, e.g. 'ROLE_USED'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use single quotes, like

```
q = "select tbuc.csId, tbuc.uId, tbuc.cId, tbui.role_type, tbuc.time as login_date"
    + ", tbuc.sessId, (case when tbui.role_type = 'ROLE_USER' then 1 else 0 end) "
    + "as assignment_submitted FROM tb_user_click tbuc, tb_user_info tbui WHERE "
    + "tbui.user_id = tbuc.uId and tbuc.csId = tbui.class_section_id;"
```

Or escape the double quotes, like

```
q = "select tbuc.csId, tbuc.uId, tbuc.cId, tbui.role_type, tbuc.time as login_date"
    + ", tbuc.sessId, (case when tbui.role_type = \"ROLE_USER\" then 1 else 0 end"
    + ") as assignment_submitted FROM tb_user_click tbuc, tb_user_info tbui WHERE "
    + "tbui.user_id = tbuc.uId and tbuc.csId = tbui.class_section_id;"
```

Or (assuming your client supports it) use a bind parameter, like

```
q = "select tbuc.csId, tbuc.uId, tbuc.cId, tbui.role_type, tbuc.time as login_date"
    + ", tbuc.sessId, (case when tbui.role_type = ? then 1 else 0 end) "
    + "as assignment_submitted FROM tb_user_click tbuc, tb_user_info tbui WHERE "
    + "tbui.user_id = tbuc.uId and tbuc.csId = tbui.class_section_id;"
```